# Does the two-party system create a political advantage for the rich?

Tags: united-states, democracy, parties, voting

Does the two-party system create a political advantage for the rich regarding political representation?

Comment: There seems to be an assumption in your question that the reason the U.S. doesn't have a socialist party is because it has a two-party system. That is not necessarily accurate. Also, I have no idea what you are asking other than that. The main question, does the two-party system advantage the rich doesn't seem to have anything to do with academic qualification. Furthermore, I'm not sure what academic qualification means.

Comment: You are better acadamically qualified when you have a college degree, this seems pretty straightforward to me. If it is indeed so that the two-party system delivers more representation to the wealthier and since wealth correlates to better academic qualifications, we can expect more American politicians with a college degree, for example.

Comment: You've removed it, so it doesn't matter now. The question I have now is: "How do you believe the two-party system creates an advantage for the rich?" This is important because it is obviously better to be rich, generally, so what does the two-party system do that other democratic political systems don't do, that creates the advantage you are describing.

Comment: Not that it's necessarily germane, but the US does have socialist parties. It's just that we only have two *major* parties. And that is at least partially due to the amount of money in US politics.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove you read my point of view, now I've asked a question without saying it, precisely to know what others think about the possibility of the two-party system actually granting an advantage for the rich in political representation ;)

Comment: @blip how does the amount of money in the US relates to the two major parties staying major specifically?

Comment: I appreciate the information, but this isn't a discussion board. Questions are asked in order to receive correct answers, not opinion. This could be an answerable question, but in order to be able to answer your question, we have to know what it is.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove I disagree. I have used stack exchange for two years now. A great deal if not most part of the questions are answered based on opinion. [This one for example.](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/28288/is-there-a-relationship-between-portugal-and-spain-being-able-to-discover-the-ne)

Comment: That's not an opinion at all. That is an empirically verifiable question, derived from historical fact. There is absolutely nothing subjective about the various effects of the Moorish occupation of Spain, nor the ways those effects altered Columbus' ability to 'discover' the New World.

Comment: @yurihbss not the amount of money in the US, but rather the amount of money in *the two major parties*. The two major parties fund races at all levels of government. When the two major parties can outspend 3rd parties by factors of 10+, it's hard for said 3rd parties to make a lot of headway.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove the opinion doesn't show itself in the content presented, but in the choice of content presented. Actually on second thought also in the content. Historical facts are shown and then people make an assumption about how that historical fact has influenced the subject in question, based on opinion.

Comment: If the underlying system is First Past the Post, then it usually takes fewer votes to get a single-party majority in seats (typically 35-40%). A single party with a majority means less scrutiny of legislation than a coalition. This may be brought about just by moving a few % of votes from one party to another. So it is easier to get absolute control than other systems I know of and FPTP can be very sensitive to election campaigns and media, ie. spending. In other words wealthy/unscrupulous individuals would probably have the easiest time changing things to their advantage under FPTP.